# Same webdriver, multiple instances, each with its own profile

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, webdriver

I need to know if I can set a proxy/profile for each driver handle.
I have the following code:

```
    def browser(url, id, user1, parolauser1, user2, parolauser2):
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:\Users\yt\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\hgv9qvsn.default")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
    driver.get(url)
    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        if "whateveriwant" in driver.title and id == 0:
            ...
            for catevreaueu in range(0,7000):
                test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file = function_test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file_for_this_first_handle()
                print test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file
                if test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file < 3:
                    another_function_for_continuing_on_this_first_handle(driver)
                else:
                    driver.close()
                    break
        if "whateveriwant" in driver.title and id == 1:
            ...
            for catevreaueu in range(0,7000):
                test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file = function_test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file_for_this_s_handle()
                print test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file
                if test_to_see_how_many_lines_are_in_a_file < 3:
                    another_function_for_continuing_on_this_second_handle(driver)
                else:
                    driver.close()
                    break
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    user_one = "userone"
    parola_user_one = "passwordforuserone"
    user_two = "usertwo"
    parola_user_two = "passwordforuser2"
    pages = ["http://www.didi.com", "http://www.didi.com/"]
    id = 0
    for page in pages:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=browser, args=(page, id, user_one, parola_user_one, user_two, parola_user_two))
        id+=1
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Now it starts two webdriver instances but as you can see both of them use the same profile.

Answer (score 0):

While it may work sometimes, I would not recommend this, if you need the same profile, create multiple copies of it. If you have a look at the [underlying code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py), you'll see that just creating an instance of webdriver changes some things around in the profile. `driver.quit` also **deletes** the profile completely.

Comment: It works, but i don't know how can i set proxies for each

Comment: As I said, it may work sometimes, but it is not that stable. A proxy is one of these examples - because firefox sets it in the profile files, and those are shared.